Baseline correction for XRD data in Origin
I have been trying to process the XRD data for a material, in Origin. I am an undergrad, new to the software, and while I have learnt to perhaps plot the data, I am not able to perform baseline correction properly. I have watched tutorials, and tried various methods, but what should ideally work does not seem to work for my plot. I have tried to pull each node down to the bottom most line in modify and delete. Is that not what I am supposed to do? Someone please point me in a different direction. Here is a screen shot of what the graph looks like currently-

So, this is an image I captured from a YT video, and ideally a similar sort of a transformation is what must happen with my plot after baseline correction. (Raw data is on the left, corrected on on the right)

I'm not able to align the peaks or correct the baseline to acheive this though.

Welcome to SE.DSP. The notion of baseline is very domain dependent, and quite ill-posed. Do you have the possibility to update your post with: a sketch of what a good baseline should look ; the data in numerical form ; potential theoretical models (like exponentials)?

Also: what is XRD?

I'm also a little clueless about what it must look like honestly, but I'll try to explain it better in the next comment. XRD is X Ray Diffraction.

@LaurentDuval, I have tried to use an image to illustrate my point and need better. Does this make it clearer?

The word you might be looking for is detrending. You can start by doing a little online search on the multiple methods to do so and see which method would suit your needs best. The most straightforward method is removing the mean, but that won’t be sufficient for you. High pass filtering could work. Wavelet-based detrending could be better. Spline interpolation based methods are also important. What software packages do you have access to?

@Jdip, Thanks, will check it out. I am currently working with a student version of Origin.

I'm not familiar with Origin. They might or might not have a detrending functionality. If they don't, you can use Octave or Python's Scipy library to detrend your data before importing it into Origin

@jdip baseline correction, detrending or background removal are different names for similar concepts

@Sevfeynn thank you for the clarification I am somehow familiar with the concept of baseine removal cf. our BEADS (Baseline Estimation And Denoising with Sparsity) algorithm. Your example seems simpler: narrower peaks, close to linear slope. Could you draw an "expected baseline" on your data? (would it be monotonous, exponential-like, etc.) to add information

@LaurentDuval I’m aware! But most software packages use the term detrend hence my comment.

yes, will try @Jdip.

yes, will try @LaurentDuval, I think I need to construct a baseline, and yes there is such an option on origin.

Thanks for the help, both of you :)
